# How to specify the location of a deltalake table in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I have a streaming data incoming which I am saving as a deltalake table using the below code:

```
cast_dataframe.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append")
.option("checkpointLocation",checkpointLocation)
.table(databasename+"."+tablename)
```

Here database is the name of database and tablename is the name of table  used to create the table.

When i use **show create the table** to show the schema of a table, the location field is pointing to a random location something like this abfs://storageaccount@storageaccount.dfs.core.net/default/db_name/table_name. I however want to point the location to my specified location. How can I do that ?

I have tried the below approach but it didn't work.

```
 cast_dataframe.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append")
 .option("checkpointLocation",checkpointLocation)
 .table(databasename+"."+tablename)
  .save(my_specified_location)
```

But the approach above doesn't work. Please help me up with this.

Answer (score 1):

`.table` and `.save` are actions and simply cannot be used at the same time. That has actually nothing to do with delta data source.

---

In the official documentation in [Delta Lake table as a sink](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-streaming.html#delta-table-as-a-sink) you can find the following:

```
.start("/delta/events") // as a path
```

which seems exactly to meet your *"I however want to point the location to my specified location."*

Comment: In addition to providing the path when you invoke `.start("/delta/path")` you can also provide the location as an option, e.g. `.option("path", "/delta/path")` and then invoke `.start()` without an argument. [docs here, scroll down to file sink options table](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks)